# Why there is need to use JsonRequestBehavior if we already have [HttpPost]?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

In ASP.NET MVC we are having option to secure our Controller's action by using `HTTPGET`/`HTTPPost`.
And for Json request there is one more option given `JsonRequestBehavior` for security.

Where JsonRequestBehavior having two options:

```
public enum JsonRequestBehavior
    {
        AllowGet = 0,
        DenyGet = 1,
    }
```

My question is just for the clearance on why there is `JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet` if we can use `HttpPost`?

Comment: There is no need to specify the `JsonRequestBehavior` in a POST method (its always allowed). But by default, `JsonRequestBehavior` is set to `DenyGet` in GET methods, so in a GET method, you must explicitly use `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet`

Answer (score 3):

DenyGet is the default setting set by MVC to protect you against a specific JSON request attack that returns data using HTTP GET.

You need to manually decide to add AllowGet, which forces you to consider the data you are exposing over the HTTP GET method.

For a detailed explanation you can read this (slightly dated) post: http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx/